# Calculate all possible combinations [RGB]

Tags: vb.net, math

I made a simple program that generates random RGB values, but i don't know how to calculate all possible combinations of RGB codes & possibly generate them ASAP, can anyone help me?

Calculation part of code:

```
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    r1 = CInt(Int((255 * Rnd()) + 0))
    g1 = CInt(Int((255 * Rnd()) + 0))
    b1 = CInt(Int((255 * Rnd()) + 0))
    If ListBox1.Items.Contains(r1 & "," & g1 & "," & b1) Then
        'number is clone of any number in Listbox1.items
        Label2.Text = Label2.Text + 1
    Else
        ListBox1.Items.Add(r1 & "," & g1 & "," & b1)
        Label1.Text = ListBox1.Items.Count.ToString
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If you want all of the combinations (in a random order?) then you should be looking to generate the complete set non-randomly and then *shuffle* them.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever what do you mean with that??

Comment: [link](http://prntscr.com/2bjnhm) screen of program is here

Comment: At the moment you're randomly generating the RGB values and adding them to a listbox in the order that you generate them. But your question also talks about "all values" - if you carry on generating them randomly, it could take a *really* long time to find the 16777216th item when 16777215 are already in the list. Better to generate all 16777216 in a separate list, then use some method to change the order they're in before adding them to the listbox.

Comment: maybe generating all values for R=0-255 G=0 B=0 then G=0-255 & R & G = 0 then G = 0-255 and just _shuffle_ them with time??

Comment: Maybe [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomized_algorithm) can be a source of inspiration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

working enough ;)

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    r1 = CInt(Int((255 * Rnd()) + 0))
    g1 = CInt(Int((255 * Rnd()) + 0))
    b1 = CInt(Int((255 * Rnd()) + 0))
    If ListBox1.Items.Contains(r1 & "," & g1 & "," & b1) Then
        'number is clone of any number in Listbox1.items
        Label2.Text = Label2.Text + 1
    Else
        ListBox1.Items.Add(r1 & "," & g1 & "," & b1)
        Label1.Text = ListBox1.Items.Count.ToString
    End If
End Sub
```